# Slick 2 fails to compile query which returns tuple

Tags: scala, slick

I'm now trying to make use of Slick's [compiled queries](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/queries.html#compiled-queries) feature. For simple queries it works fine, but queries involving joins with Tuple return type cause compilation error.

Here's one of the dao methods I'm trying to rewrite with compiled queries:

```
def getByArticle(id: Int)(implicit session: JdbcBackend#Session) = {
      comments
        .filter(_.articleId === id)
        .leftJoin(users).on(_.userId === _.id)
        .list
    }
```

When I'm trying to modify it like that

```
val byArticleCompiled = Compiled((id: Column[Int]) => comments
  .filter(_.articleId === id)
  .leftJoin(users).on(_.userId === _.id)
)

def getByArticle(id: Int)(implicit session: JdbcBackend#Session) = byArticleCompiled(id).list
```

the following compilation error occurs:

> [error]
>   Computation of type
>   CommentsRepositoryComponentImpl.this.profile.simple.Column[Int] =>
>   scala.slick.lifted.WrappingQuery[(CommentsRepositoryComponentImpl.this.Comments,
>   CommentsRepositoryComponentImpl.this.Users),(CommentsRepositoryComponentImpl.this.Comments#TableElementType,
>   CommentsRepositoryComponentImpl.this.Users#TableElementType)] cannot
>   be compiled (as type C) [error]     val byArticleCompiled =
>   Compiled((id: Column[Int]) => comments

Is there any conceptual problem behind that or I'm simply doing somehting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a problem with the `Executable` typeclass for these queries produced by a join. As a work-around, appending a dummy operation like `.withFilter(_ => true)` makes it compile. We'll look into it for 2.0.2 (https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/746).

Comment: thanks a lot. I've placed some sorting (which is required anyway) after the join and now it works.